Play Video from URL in Webview. But Video stops frequently automatically. Controls doesn't work
In WebView Video stops frequently automatically. Controls doesn't work. Default Play/Pause buttom appears in center of video. Sometimes cause flickering issues with video controls.
I want to achieve the functionality of playing Video from URL in Webview (InApp). I have used flutter packages - webview_flutter 4.7.0  and flutter_inappwebview .But both behaving same. causing flickering issues with video controls.
Expecting proper Solution.

Why do you want to open a video in webview? Is there any reason for that? If you just want to play video from url use video_player package

Is there a reason you want it to play in a webview and not just directly using something like the video_player package?

Initially I have also tried video_player package. But It doesn't provide default controls like  Play/Pause button or Video progress indicator, mute/Unmute buttons. Custom controls also i tried to design , But It doesn't work properly.

Would need to see code that is not working.  The idea is that you build your own UI with the player being just another widget, many people use this package so I find it hard to believe you can't do what you want.
